# Trying to create a discord.py bot which welcomes users, but doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, discord.py

i have only started to look around and figure how things work with discord.py bot. Tried making a bot that welcomes people in a certain channel. But no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to be working. The code executes and the on_ready fires. But its not welcoming the user like its supposed to. Can someone help?

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from discord.ext.commands import Bot 
    from discord import Color
    import asyncio  
    import datetime
    
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
    
    client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")
    client.remove_command("help")
    
    @client.event 
    async def on_ready():
        print("Created by Goodboi")
        print(client.user.name)
        print("-----")
    
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xe8744f,
        description=f"Welcome to the discord server",)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{member.mention}",icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}",icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow
    
        channel = client.get_channel(id=) #usedid
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        
    client.run('token') #usedtoken
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a traceback if possible/say what exactly does not work/goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to get channel like this

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):

        embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xe8744f,
        description=f"Welcome to the discord server",)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{member.mention}",icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}",icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel_id) #usedid
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You have built in the same error as the user. How he gets the channel is totally fine/working. His error is in the embed itself, but you could only know that if you tried the code.

Comment: For some reason in my bot client.get_channel(id) doesn't work so i had to use the method i showed above. With datetime.datetime.utcnow() you are completly right.

Comment: This one seemed to  work for me! Also, I think I finally understood how the embed actually works. Thank you! Just had another question, the member.mention in embed.set_author returns the user's ID in the format <@id>, do you know how I can mention the user by username. And also how to return the username in username#discrimantor in other scenarios? Thank you!

Comment: @GOODBOIXD You can't mention someone in the `author` filed. Use a `field` or `description` instead. If you just want to display the name in the `author` filed you can use `member` as an argument. (`member = discord.Member`)

Comment: @Dominik thank you, used description. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you did wrong is passing no brackets to your `datetime.datetime.utcnow` "function" which gives out the following error:

```py
TypeError: Expected datetime.datetime or Embed.Empty received builtin_function_or_method instead
```

If you put brackets behind the definition of your timestamp it should work:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xe8744f,
                          description=f"Welcome to the discord server", )
    embed.set_author(name=f"{member.mention}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # Added brackets

    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID) # No "id=" needed
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

***You can also have a look at the docs:*** https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime

Comment: thank you for pointing out the datetime error!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, though, can be improved in many ways, but if you asked for this, then here is it.

```
 @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member) : 
       channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL ID) # First we need to get the channel we want to post our welcome message.

       embed = discord.Embed(
               colour=0xe8744f ,
               description='Welcome to the discord server' ,
               timestamp=datetime.utcnow()
       )
       embed.set_author(name=f'{member.mention}' , icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}')
       embed.set_footer(text=f'{member.guild}' , icon_url=f'{member.guild.icon_url}')
       await channel.send(embed=embed) #Send the embed
```